# Short but impossible math problem

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Given these four equations/inequalities:

```
1x=2
2x=4
3x=3
4x>8
```

What is x?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The answer is:

> The "<" symbol

Why?

> In some programming languages, "<=" means "is less than or equal to", and "<>" means "is not equal to".

Comment: From [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34644/170816): "Just for trivia, <> was chosen in some languages because it can be interpreted as "less than or greater than", or in other words, not equal."  (The longer you live ...)

Comment: And <> is not necessarily the same as !=. Some objects it doesn't make sense to compare < or >.

Comment: Precisely correct!

Comment: Hah. And here I though it was about `x` being another representation of `><` in a smaller print.

Answer (score 16):

Answer: x is

> a *variable* (as in programming)

That's because

> the given "equations/inequalities" are in fact (some dialect of) BASIC code, so 1,2,3,4 at the beginning of the each line are just labels/line numbers. So, it's a perfectly valid program consisting of 3 assignments (lines 1-3) to the same variable `x` and 1 comparison in line 4 (the result of which is not assigned to any variable). Better formatting and comments:
>
> ```
>  1 x = 2 'assign 2 to x (creating a new variable, declaration is not required in BASIC)
>  2 x = 4 'assign 4 to x
>  3 x = 3 'assign 3 to x
>  4 x > 8 'compare x with 8, returning false (0)
> ```

P.S.

> If `x` is required to be a number, my answer is `x = 3` (this will be the value of `x` after running this code).

Comment: Very clever! Headed in the right direction, but not what I was going for. Also, your P.S. is not necessary, because rot13(k vf abg n ahzore)

Comment: rot13(vs vg jnf onfvp gurer jbhyq unir orra fcnprf orgjrra gur ynoryf/yvar ahzoref naq gur pbzznaqf)

Answer (score 4):

X could be operator (IS NOT)

```
!
```

Because

```
1x=2
2x=4
3x=3
4x>8
```

are always either true or false conditions in any programming language.

```
1!=2    //Always True
2!=4    //Always True
3!=3    //Always False
4!>8    //Always True
```

Comment: Huh?  What language supports !> ?

Comment: @LorenPechtel You are right .. thank you for ponting out mistake.

Comment: @LorenPechtel T-SQL

Answer (score 2):

x could be:

> (π/2)!

where the

> ! is a not operator

Comment: ! seems more like a factorial in the last context at least.

Comment: Seconded--! as negation precedes, not follows.  Trailing it only means factorial.

Comment: @LorenPechtel In the context, the first line would be read 1(p/2)!=2 where "!=" means "not equals".